# Process Asynchronous Calls in Sequence

Tags: c#, .net, azure, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I am making a bunch or `asynchronous calls` to Azure Table Storage. For obvious reasons insertion of these records are not in the same order as they were invoked.

I am planning to introduce `ConcurrentQueue` to ensure sequence. Following sample code written as a POC seems to achieve desired result.

> I am wondering is this the best way I can ensure asynchronous calls
>   will be completed in sequence?

```
public class ProductService
{
    ConcurrentQueue<string> ordersQueue = new ConcurrentQueue<string>();
    //Place make calls here
    public void PlaceOrder()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Parallel.For(0, 100, (i) =>
            {
                string item = "Product " + i;
                ordersQueue.Enqueue(item);
                Console.WriteLine("Placed Order: " + item);
                Task.Delay(2000).Wait();
            });

        });

    }

    //Process calls in sequence, I am hoping concurrentQueue will be consistent.
    public void Deliver()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while(true)
            {
                string productId;
                ordersQueue.TryDequeue(out productId);
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(productId))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Delivered: " + productId);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. If you want to do things in order, then using APIs for concurrent, `Parallel`, execution is never going to be a good start. 2. Asynchronous approaches are good when you avoid blocking operations, but only if you convert the actual blocking operations to be asynchronous: ie. don't block the thread of execution on a lock (`ConcurrentQueue<T>.Enqueue`).

Comment: First of All Task.Delay is not a good choice.... and your hundred items will De-Queue one by one, that means now you have 100 items to insert and each will be an async request to Azure. Suppose you have 8 core machine and you have 100 Tasks, you cannot assure which will complete when

Comment: Can you please describe what you're trying to do at a slightly more abstract level? For example, are you just trying to asynchronously trying to call an in-order series of azure inserts?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to process records asynchronously and sequentially this sounds like a perfect fit for TPL Dataflow's `ActionBlock`. Simply create a block with the action to execute and post records to it. It supports `async` actions and keeps order:

```
var block = new ActionBlock<Product>(async product =>
{
    await product.ExecuteAsync();
});

block.Post(new Product());
```

It also supports processing in parallel and bounded capacity if you need.

Answer (score 1):

Try using Microsoft's Reactive Framework.

This worked for me:

```
IObservable<Task<string>> query =
    from i in Observable.Range(0, 100, Scheduler.Default)
    let item = "Product " + i
    select AzureAsyncCall(item);

query
    .Subscribe(async x =>
    {
        var result = await x;
        /* do something with result */
    });
```

The `AzureAsyncCall` call signature I used was `public Task<string> AzureAsyncCall(string x)`.

I dropped in a bunch of `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` calls to ensure I was getting the right async behaviour in my test code. It worked well.

All the calls were asynchronous and serialized one after the other.